# No DATA outlet in wall socket - Internet with coaxial

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, internet, catv

We are new to Germany and we have no idea how the coaxial internet works. Our provider told us that there is cable access to our address but now that the router arrived I find that we don't have the necessary outlet. We only have R and TV while the SAT port is empty. Is there a way to have cable access in this case or should we cancel the plan etc?

Could there be an adapter that we can buy or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be able to get your internet provider help get the router connected.

Comment: There may be cable access, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's run from their demarcation location to your specific residence.  It may just mean that it *could* be run, not that it *has* been run.  Probably a clarification from your provider would be in order as well.

Comment: The cable is probably for cable TV or CATV. Many cable providers are able to deliver internet over cable.

Comment: Odds are good one of your neighbors has the same provider—why not ask what they have?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the responses! Turns out that indeed there is no cable in the apartment but the address could have connection if requested. As there is no way to have a cable connection soon we switche our contract to DSL that we do have and hope for the best (same as our neighbors after all).